# News sample skill returns unauthorized error

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, bing-news-search-api

I am trying to use the experimental skills provided by the bot framework. I downloaded the code for the  [news skill](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/samples/news/) and created all azure resources. I got the bing key from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis/bing-news-search-api) and placed it in my appsettings.json I also updated all my config values to my Luis app.
I am testing through emulator. When I run the code I go through the dialog successfully, it asks me for the topic I want to get news about and my country and then at the point where it has to get the news articles I get the following error.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone have any idea what am I missing? I tried the bing API through postman using the same key I have in my appsettings and it is working fine.

[image: postman]

Should I do an additional step other than just download the code and update all the config values?
I don't know what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created bing using [new](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis) marketing portal.
Here are [endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-news-search/reference/endpoints#endpoints) for Bing news using REST API.
[image]
Doc Location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/

Comment: i don't see a place where I should enter the endpoints, the appsettings.json doesn't have such a parameter. Is there somewhere else I should add the endpoints?

Comment: Where can I get the new release? I am using the latest Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.NewsSearch available on nuget

Comment: There is known issue with bing new key using in client library. will update once new SDK releases.